# How to find the total of each column in 2D-array

Tags: c#

Note: the array and total of columns should be appear as below figure (numbers should not be
the same as figure below, numbers should be random)

```
5 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 4 5 6 7 8 8 9 9
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 11 1 1
```

The total of each column

```
33 29 31 32 33 34 35 45 36 36
```

`enter coddouble[,] a = new double[10, 10];
            Random x = new Random();
            string s = "";

```
        for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
            {
                a[r, c] = x.Next(1, 21);
                s = s + a[r, c].ToString() + "\t";


            }
        }
        textBox1.Text = s;e here`
```

this is how to print the arry now how to find the sum of each column

Comment: i can't find the total of each column

Comment: Nice Requirement. BTW, what have you tried so far to solve this?

Comment: Please add the definition of the array so we know how you declared it.

Comment: i can declare this 2d-array but the problem is how to find the total of each column and print the total below its column

Comment: can you add how you are declaring the array.

Answer (score 3):

It is very basic in array implementation.

There are many ways to achieve this.One of my preferred way by iterating over the array structure using simple loop like this.

```
static int array[10][10];
//or like
int[,] array = new int[,]
{
   <declare array structure>
};
int i, j, rowlength=10, columnlength=10, sum = 0; //assuming your order 10 as given example .To make it dynamic use array.Length

sum = 0;
for (j = 0; j < columnlength; ++j)
{
    for (i = 0; i < rowlength; ++i)
    {
        sum = sum + array[i][j];
    }
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Summation of {0}th column is {1}", j,sum)); 
    sum=0;       
}
```

Comment: this way is to find the sum of all the elements,but i need to find the sum of each column

Comment: why is your application web form?console,windows form or what?add more context to question.

Comment: it is windows application

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr2d = new int[5];
arr2d[0] = {1,2,3,4,5};
// etc...

var arr = new int[arr2d.length];

for(int i=0; i<arr2d.length; i++) {
    var item = arr2d[i];
    for(int j=0; j<item.length; j++) {
        arr[i] += item[j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below code. It generic code and can work on any number of column, you don't need to hardcode number of column. columnSum List contain the sum of individual column

```
var array2D = Get2DArray(); //some function to populate, you can have your own way to populate your 2D array

List<int> columnSum = new List<int>();

for (int j = 0; j < array2D.length ; ++j)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array2D[j].length; ++i)
    {
        sum = sum + array2D[i][j];
    }

    columnSum.Add(sum); // columnSum List contain the sum of individual column
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using your code.

What I did was sum the column you add the number to the array. This is assuming c is column and r is row.

```
double[,] a = new double[10, 10];
Random x = new Random();
string s = "";
var colsum = new List<int>();
for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++)
{
    var col = 0;
    for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
    {
        col += x.Next(1, 21);
        a[r, c] = col;
        s = s + a[r, c].ToString() + "\t";
    }
    colsum.Add(col);
}
foreach(var col in colsum){
    Console.WriteLine(colsum.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[,] data = new int[,] {
                {5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                {2 ,2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9},
                {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
                {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
                {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5},
                {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4},
                {7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7},
                {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
                {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 1, 1}
            };
            int[] sum = new int[10];

            for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
                {
                    if (row == 0)
                    {
                        sum[col] = data[row, col];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sum[col] += data[row, col];
                    }
                }
            }

             List<List<int>> data2 = new List<List<int>>() {
                new List<int>() {5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                new List<int>() {2 ,2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9},
                new List<int>() {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                new List<int>() {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
                new List<int>() {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
                new List<int>() {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5},
                new List<int>() {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4},
                new List<int>() {7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7},
                new List<int>() {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
                new List<int>() {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 1, 1}
            };

            //using linq
            int[] sum2 = data2.Select(s => s.Select((t, i) => new { num = t, col = i })).SelectMany(u => u).GroupBy(v => v.col).ToList().Select(w => w.Select(x => x.num).Sum()).ToArray();

        }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple - just 2 nested `for` loops like this

```
static double[] SumColumns(double[,] source)
{
    int rowCount = source.GetLength(0);
    int colCount = source.GetLength(1);
    var colSums = new double[colCount];
    for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < colCount; col++)
            colSums[col] += source[row, col];
    return colSums;
}
```

Sample usage with your code:

```
int rows = 10, cols = 10;
var a = new double[rows, cols];
var x = new Random();
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
    {
        a[r, c] = x.Next(1, 21);
        if (c > 0) sb.Append("\t");
        sb.Append(a[r, c]);
    }
    sb.AppendLine();
}
var colsSums = SumColumns(a);
for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
{
    if (c > 0) sb.Append("\t");
    sb.Append(colsSums[c]);
}
var s = sb.ToString();
textBox1.Text = s;
```

Comment: i really don't know what to do none of these answers work

Comment: @sara You probably should tell what exactly doesn't work for you

Comment: all of these answers are about the summation of the array this example is about having random elements in 2d-array  and i have to calculate the summation of each column then print the summation under its column

Comment: @sara Have you tried any of them? IMO most are doing what you want. Or you don't see how to use? See my updated answer, isn't that what you want - calculate sum per each column and print it?

Comment: in sample with my code : there is an error with sumcolums how to correct it?

Comment: @sara I've put another (an hopefully the last) update for you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but you can have it by the following single line,

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, sample.GetLength(1)).Select(c => Enumerable.Range(0, sample.GetLength(0)).Select(r => sample[r, c]).Sum()).ToArray();
```

---

**Test with sample data**

```
var sample = new int[10, 10]
{
    { 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1 },
    { 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8,  9, 9 },
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1 },
    { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,  2, 2 },
    { 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,  3, 3 },
    { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,  5, 5 },
    { 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,  4, 4 },
    { 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,  7, 7 },
    { 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,  3, 3 },
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 1, 1 }
};

var row = sample.GetLength(0);
var column = sample.GetLength(1);

var result = Enumerable.Range(0, column).Select(c => Enumerable.Range(0, row).Select(r => sample[r, c]).Sum()).ToArray();
```

> Gets sum of each column in an array with; **33, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 45, 36, 36**